# Major trouble with nRF24L01+ controllers and the RF24 library

Tags: gpio, networking, wireless, arduino, rfid

I've had a hellish last three days. All I've wanted to do is get an Arduino Uno and a Raspberry Pi B+ talking to eachother with [these little guys](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E594ZX0), and after following many different tutorials, I've had absolutely no luck.

Some of the tutorials I have been following to get the circuit set up are these:

- http://hack.lenotta.com/arduino-raspberry-pi-switching-light-with-nrf24l01/
- http://blog.the-jedi.co.uk/2013/10/07/nrf24l01-and-raspberry-pi/
- http://arduino-for-beginners.blogspot.com/2013/02/setup-nordic-nrf24l01-rf-modules-to.html
- http://blog.riyas.org/2014/02/setting-up-nordic-nrf24l01-rf-modules-raspberrypi-home-automation.html

I have looked up the [exact pin out](http://data.designspark.info/uploads/images/53bc258dc6c0425cb44870b50ab30621) of the Raspberry Pi B+ and used it to double check that I am getting the pin out correct, considering that most of the tutorials are using RPi model B's.

The libraries I have tried using are the following:

- https://github.com/stanleyseow/RF24
- https://github.com/gnulnulf/RF24
- https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24

At first I tried using the one by Stanley Seow, but it had been updated a bit since the tutorial so I was getting function input errors while trying to run the code that comes with the tutorials listed above. I was able to try out the examples included with the library, but none of them worked. Whenever I would run the function `radio.printDetails()`, I would get an output like the following:

On the Pi, with CE going to GPIO 25 and CSN going to GPIO 8 (CE0)

```
===============SPI Configuration ====================
CSN Pin      = CEO (PI Hardware Driven)
CE Pin       = Custom GPIO25
Clock Speed  = 8 Mhz
==================== NRF Config ===========================
Status    = 0xff RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_PO-1 = 0xfffffffffff 0xfffffffffffff
TX_ADDR  = 0xfffffffffff
... = 0xfffff
... = 0xfffff
... = 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff

...

Model = nRF24L01
CRC Length = 16 bits
PA Power = PA_MAX
```

On the arduino, with the pins quadruple checked and in the right spot I get the same thing, everything is `0xff...fff`

What could be wrong here? I've tried all of the examples included in all of the libraries listed above and everything either gives me the `radio.printDetails()` output listed above or one with all `0x0000`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. What happened was that when I first got the modules I accidentally hooked them both up to a 5V rail instead of the recommended 3.3V, or at least this is my best guess as to why nothing was working. I got another pair of the RF modules today and made sure to only connect them to 3.3V and they work absolutely perfectly with all of the tutorials listed above.